# Electron upload local file to Google Drive using googleapis

Tags: node.js, electron, google-drive-api

I got a script for a screen Recorder on github using Electron, a simple screen recorder that saves a local video file, then I am trying to upload the file video to google drive automatically using googleapis but the file gets created but it's EMPTY, I tried many things, at this point I am not sure what to do anymore.

save-to-google.js

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const fs = require('fs');

const key = require('./google/apiKey.json'); // Ensure path is correct
const scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];

const auth = new google.auth.JWT(key.client_email, null, key.private_key, scopes);

// Initialize the Drive API
const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });

//upload File
async function uploadFile(fileName, folderId, filePath, mime) {
    console.log("starting Upload")
    return new Promise((resolve, rejected) => {

        var fileMetaData = {
            name: fileName,
            parents: [folderId]
        }

        drive.files.create({
            resource: fileMetaData,
            media: {
                body: fs.createReadStream(filePath),
                mimeType: mime
            },
            fields: 'id'
        }, function (err, file) {
            if (err) {
                return rejected(err)
            }
            console.log("Uploaded successfully")
            resolve(file)
        });

    })
}
```

render.js

```
const { desktopCapturer, remote } = require('electron');
const { writeFile, createWriteStream, write } = require('fs');
const { dialog, Menu } = remote;
const googleDrive = require('./save-to-google.js');
const folderId = require('./google/gdriveFolder.json');
const mimeExt = require('./google/mime.json')
const path = require('path')


// Global state
let mediaRecorder; // MediaRecorder instance to capture footage
const recordedChunks = [];

// Buttons
const videoElement = document.querySelector('video');
// Mute the playback
videoElement.muted = true;


const startBtn = document.getElementById('startBtn');
startBtn.onclick = e => {
  mediaRecorder.start();
  startBtn.classList.add('is-danger');
  startBtn.innerText = 'Recording';

  // Clear the previous recorded chunks
  recordedChunks.length = 0;

};

const stopBtn = document.getElementById('stopBtn');

stopBtn.onclick = e => {
  mediaRecorder.stop();
  startBtn.classList.remove('is-danger');
  startBtn.innerText = 'Start';
};

const videoSelectBtn = document.getElementById('videoSelectBtn');
videoSelectBtn.onclick = getVideoSources;

// Get the available video sources
async function getVideoSources() {
  const inputSources = await desktopCapturer.getSources({
    types: ['window', 'screen']
  });

  const videoOptionsMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(
    inputSources.map(source => {
      return {
        label: source.name,
        click: () => selectSource(source)
      };
    })
  );


  videoOptionsMenu.popup();
}

// Change the videoSource window to record
async function selectSource(source) {

  videoSelectBtn.innerText = source.name;

  const constraints = {
    audio: {
      mandatory: {
        chromeMediaSource: 'desktop'
      }
    },
    video: {
      mandatory: {
        chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
        chromeMediaSourceId: source.id
      }
    }
  };

  // Create a Stream
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia(constraints);

  // Preview the source in a video element
  videoElement.srcObject = stream;
  videoElement.play();

  // Create the Media Recorder
  const options = { mimeType: 'video/webm; codecs=vp9' };
  mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);

  // Register Event Handlers
  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
  mediaRecorder.onstop = handleStop;

  // Updates the UI
}

// Captures all recorded chunks
function handleDataAvailable(e) {
  console.log('video data available');
  recordedChunks.push(e.data);
}

// Saves the video file on stop and uploads to Google Drive
async function handleStop(e) {
  const blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
    type: 'video/webm; codecs=vp9'
  });

  const buffer = Buffer.from(await blob.arrayBuffer());

  // Save the video file locally
  const { filePath } = await dialog.showSaveDialog({
    buttonLabel: 'Save video',
    defaultPath: `vid-${Date.now()}.webm`
  });

  if (filePath) {
    try {
      writeFile(filePath, buffer, async () => {
        console.log('video saved successfully!');

        const fileName = path.basename(filePath);
        const folder = folderId['tmp-video'];
        const mimeType = mimeExt.webm;

        const response = await googleDrive.uploadFile(fileName, folder, filePath, mimeType);
        console.log('Uploaded to Google Drive', response);

      });

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed during the save or upload process:', error);
    }
  }
}
```

this is the stack trace I get, I don't know if is usefull

```
Launching Application

2024-01-05T14:32:10.491ZE [7264:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:139:Connect Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_user_shell
2024-01-05T14:32:10.491ZE [19256:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:139:Connect Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_user_shell
2024-01-05T14:32:10.492ZE [7264:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:622:operator() Failed to connect to the server: NOT_FOUND: Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_user_shell [type.googleapis.com/drive.ds.Status='UNAVAILABLE_RESOURCE']
=== Source Location Trace: ===
apps/drive/fs/ipc/shell_ipc_client.cc:140

2024-01-05T14:32:10.493ZE [7264:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:139:Connect Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_user_shell
2024-01-05T14:32:10.493ZE [9996:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:139:Connect Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_user_shell
2024-01-05T14:32:10.493ZE [7264:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:622:operator() Failed to connect to the server: NOT_FOUND: Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_user_shell [type.googleapis.com/drive.ds.Status='UNAVAILABLE_RESOURCE']
=== Source Location Trace: ===
apps/drive/fs/ipc/shell_ipc_client.cc:140

2024-01-05T14:32:10.493ZE [9996:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:622:operator() Failed to connect to the server: NOT_FOUND: Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_user_shell [type.googleapis.com/drive.ds.Status='UNAVAILABLE_RESOURCE']
=== Source Location Trace: ===
apps/drive/fs/ipc/shell_ipc_client.cc:140

2024-01-05T14:32:10.493ZE [9996:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:139:Connect Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_user_shell
2024-01-05T14:32:10.493ZE [17116:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:139:Connect Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_user_shell
2024-01-05T14:32:10.493ZE [9996:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:622:operator() Failed to connect to the server: NOT_FOUND: Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_user_shell [type.googleapis.com/drive.ds.Status='UNAVAILABLE_RESOURCE']
=== Source Location Trace: ===
apps/drive/fs/ipc/shell_ipc_client.cc:140

2024-01-05T14:32:10.493ZE [17116:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:622:operator() Failed to connect to the server: NOT_FOUND: Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_user_shell [type.googleapis.com/drive.ds.Status='UNAVAILABLE_RESOURCE']
=== Source Location Trace: ===
apps/drive/fs/ipc/shell_ipc_client.cc:140

2024-01-05T14:32:10.493ZE [17116:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:139:Connect Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_user_shell
2024-01-05T14:32:10.493ZE [17116:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:622:operator() Failed to connect to the server: NOT_FOUND: Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_user_shell [type.googleapis.com/drive.ds.Status='UNAVAILABLE_RESOURCE']
=== Source Location Trace: ===
apps/drive/fs/ipc/shell_ipc_client.cc:140

2024-01-05T14:32:10.493ZE [19256:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:622:operator() Failed to connect to the server: NOT_FOUND: Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_user_shell [type.googleapis.com/drive.ds.Status='UNAVAILABLE_RESOURCE']
=== Source Location Trace: ===
apps/drive/fs/ipc/shell_ipc_client.cc:140

2024-01-05T14:32:10.494ZE [9996:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:139:Connect Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_user_shell
2024-01-05T14:32:10.494ZE [9996:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:622:operator() Failed to connect to the server: NOT_FOUND: Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_user_shell [type.googleapis.com/drive.ds.Status='UNAVAILABLE_RESOURCE']
=== Source Location Trace: ===
apps/drive/fs/ipc/shell_ipc_client.cc:140

2024-01-05T14:32:10.494ZE [17116:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:139:Connect Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_user_shell
2024-01-05T14:32:10.494ZE [17116:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:622:operator() Failed to connect to the server: NOT_FOUND: Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_user_shell [type.googleapis.com/drive.ds.Status='UNAVAILABLE_RESOURCE']
=== Source Location Trace: ===
apps/drive/fs/ipc/shell_ipc_client.cc:140
```